# If there is the Solr Query for 2 different date columns

Tags: solr, hive

We have created the table in Hive, and the records from the table are indexed in Apache Solr.

The table has fields like MY_START_DATE AND MY_END_DATE.

When triggering the hive query as below:

```
SELECT MY_TABLE.COMPANY_NAME, MY_TABLE.MY_START_DATE, MY_TABLE.MY_END_DATE
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE 1 = 1  AND 
     FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MY_TABLE.MY_START_DATE),'yyyy/MM/dd') >= 
     FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('07/02/2016', 'MM/dd/yyyy' ),'yyyy/MM/dd') AND 
     FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MY_TABLE.MY_END_DATE),'yyyy/MM/dd') <= 
     FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('07/13/2016', 'MM/dd/yyyy' ),'yyyy/MM/dd') 
LIMIT 1000;
```

It gives total of 292 records.

But when trying to execute the same in Solr as below

```
MY_START_DATE:[2016-07-02 TO * ] AND MY_END_DATE:[ * TO 2016-07-13]
```

It gives only 47 records.

Can someone please help to get the correct Solr query, which will match with Hive query?

Comment: Are you sure your Solr indexing doesn't perform updates?

Comment: Start by querying Solr for one of the ids returned in your Hive query, but not in your Solr query to determine if the document has been indexed and all, and then you can start to find out why it isn't being returned.